# Django File Uploads and Model FileField

Tags: python, django, file, upload

I'm sooo close... but I don't quite see the connection from the upload view to the model. When I use the callback in the model's `FileField` the upload works, but *I'm not sure where the actual file copy is taking place.* The goal is to make sure that `chunking` is happening, but the file copy action seems to be hidden somewhere?

Here's what I have:

**Model:**

```
def get_media_upload_dir(instance, filename):
    user_id  = instance.user.id
    upload_dir = "%s/%d/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, user_id, filename)
    print "Upload dir set to: %s" % upload_dir
    return upload_dir

class MediaFile(models.Model):
    media_file     = models.FileField(upload_to=get_media_upload_dir)
    download_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**View:**

```
def file_upload(request, course_id):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded = form.cleaned_data['file_upload']
            mediaFile = MediaFile(media_file=uploaded,
                                owner=request.user.profile,
                                creator=request.user.profile)
            mediaFile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/course/%s/' % course_id)
    else:
        form = FileUploadForm()
    return render_to_response('course/file_upload.html', {'form':form,'course':course}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Have you read http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#handling-uploaded-files ? It seems to be what you're looking for. Don't want to answer because not sure what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storing happens here: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L90. Django uses it's own API for accessing the file storage: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/. But if chunking is what you need you can go with Bartek's proposal!